# Adding checkboxes in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxfor

I have searched and was unable to find a way to display checkboxes in my view.  I have 2 entities:  Assignment and Chore which is a one-to-many relationship (one assignment, many chores)

```
public class Chore
{
    public System.Guid ChoreId { get; set; }
    public string ChoreName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PointValue { get; set; }
}

public class Assignment
{
    public int AssignmentId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid RecipientId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Completed { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime AssignedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CompletedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Chore> Chores { get; set; }
}
```

How can I display a list of all possible chores That I can select whenever I want to create an assignment?

Comment: MVC does not have a checkbox list helper but there are plenty of examples out there including [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: please see this example                       http://maheshde.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/aspnet-mvc-how-to-publish-checkbox-list_30.html